# I keep timing out calculating the mean of a subset

Tags: python-3.x, performance, loops, io

I have a working block of code, but the online judge on HackerEarth keeps returning a timing error.  I'm new to coding and so i don't know the tricks to speed up my code.  any help would be much appreciated!

```
N, Q = map(int, input().split())
#N is the length of the array, Q is the number of queries
in_list =input().split()
#input is a list of integers separated by a space
array = list(map(int, in_list))
from numpy import mean
means=[]
for i in range(Q):
   L, R = map(int, input().split())
   m= int(mean(array[L-1:R]))
   means.append(m)

for i in means:
    print(i)
```

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to avoid doing `O(N)` operations in the loop. Currently both the slicing and the `mean` call (which needs to sum up the items in the slice) are both that slow. So you need a better algorithm.

I'll suggest that you do some preprocessing on the list of numbers so that you can figure out the sum of the values that *would be* in the slice (without actually doing a slice and adding them up). By using `O(N)` space, you can do the calculation of each sum in `O(1)` time (making the whole process take `O(N + Q)` time rather than `O(N * Q)`).

Here's a quick solution I put together, using `itertools.accumulate` to find a cumulative sum of the list items. I don't actually save the items themselves, as the cumulative sum is enough.

```
from itertools import accumulate

N, Q = map(int, input().split())
sums = list(accumulate(map(int, input().split())))

for _ in range(Q):
    L, R = map(int, input().split())
    print((sums[R] - (sums[L-1] if L > 0 else 0)) / (R-L+1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!  I am looking for hints, but I have no idea how to even begin to do this.  Slicing seems to be the death of speedy programs, so figuring out how to do it without slicing will be SUPER helpful.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an actual solution, which if you're still working on the problem yourself, you might want to skip.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is really helpful.